# LARAVEL FACEBOOKPROVIDER

Tags: facebook, laravel

I'm having trouble with the recent facebook update with their API.

I was having an error that said

> **Laravel FacebookProvider Error. Undefined variable: access_token.**

I found another question where they said to do this :

In **`vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php`**

Replace

```
parse_str($body, $data);
return $access_token;
```

With

```
parse_str($body, $data);
$json = json_decode(key($data));
return $json->access_token;
```

After I made those changes, now i'm having this error

> **FatalErrorException in FacebookProvider.php line 67:
>   Cannot access empty property**

Here's the link : https://concoura.com

Comment: What is the meaning of the link: is it spam or is it needed to understand the question?

Comment: Its the url of the website where the error is

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever modify vendor files. Instead, update your package through composer. This was fixed awhile ago as the `FacebookProvider` has changed greatly and utilizes a completely different method to retrieve and provide the access code.

```
 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getAccessTokenResponse($code)
{
    $postKey = (version_compare(ClientInterface::VERSION, '6') === 1) ? 'form_params' : 'body';
    $response = $this->getHttpClient()->post($this->getTokenUrl(), [
        $postKey => $this->getTokenFields($code),
    ]);
    $data = [];
    $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    return Arr::add($data, 'expires_in', Arr::pull($data, 'expires'));
}
```

Comment: How can i upgrade only this part?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved with

> composer require laravel/socialite:^2.0

Tested with Laravel 5.2 and 5.3